# How can I assign a formula when not float value is specified on input function?

Tags: python

```
value1 = 0.324
value2 = 0.438
value3 = float (input ("please enter value "))
```

if no value is specified, i want to execute the formula `value3 = (lsl + usl)/2`

```
value3 = (lsl + usl)/2
print(value3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
value1 = 0.324
value2 = 0.438
try :
    value3 = float (input ("please enter value "))
except :
    value3 = (lsl + usl)/2
print(value3)
```

Comment: Excellent my friend, I posted the question with a mistake but you got it anyway.
THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking to get the average of `value1` and `value2`:

```
value1 = 0.324
value2 = 0.438
try :
    value3 = float (input ("please enter value "))
except :
    value3 = (value1 + value2)/2
print(value3)
```